# RedirectPermanent htaccess regex

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i would like to make redirection 301 in htaccess for wordpress post to my home page

exemple work:
old post = `https://www.example.com/keywordkeyworkeyword/`

```
RedirectPermanent /keywordkeyworkeyword/ https://www.example.com
```

but for some articles I don't have the end of the url !

exemple no work:
old post = `https://www.example.com/keywordkeyworkeywordKey...`

```
RedirectPermanent /keywordkeyworkeywordKey(.*)$ https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RedirectPermanent` (mod_alias) directive does not take a regex, it uses simple prefix matching.

You need to use `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) near the top of your `.htaccess`, *before* the existing WordPress directives.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^keywordkeyworkeywordKey https://www.example.com/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The above redirects any URL that starts `/keywordkeyworkeywordKey` to the homepage (root URL).

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues. You'll need to clear your browser cache before testing.